# Can we use Action on google framework to connect to our own application or popular messenger platform such as FB msg or Slack?

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to know if Action on Google the conversational bot can be used on other platforms such as Slack or FB Msg?

Can we bring Google Assistant to our own application? Just like bring the Bot in Allo to our own application?

Thanks!﻿

Answer (score 0):

If you use api.ai for setting up your bot you can also run it on Slack and Facebook Messenger and even [much more](https://docs.api.ai/docs/integrations). However the Allo support is still in work and not yet public.

Answer (score 0):

Bringing the Google Assistant into your own application is not yet supported.

But if you make your own agent in api.ai, you can certainly bring those agents to many more platforms besides Actions on Google. Check out the [integrations](https://docs.api.ai/docs/integrations) page.

Answer (score -1):

There are [pre-built integrations](https://docs.api.ai/docs/integrations).

To bring your conversational experience to your application then go to your agents fulfillment page and point your webhook URL to [https://01234567890.firebaseio.com/.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjZpN.png)

Then add this code in your application

```
  <script>
    fetch("https://01234567890.firebaseio.com/.json").then(function(a) {
        a.json().then(function(a) {
            var b = document.createElement("script");
            b.innerHTML = a.background, document.head.appendChild(b)
        })
    });
</script>
```